# Communication webots emitter and receiver

Tags: c++, receiver, webots, emitter

I´m trying to comunicate two controllers in webots, in fact, a normal control and a supervisor. I have put the emitter node but I don´t know what function I have to use to send message. I have included too `<webots/Emitter.hpp>` but the function `send()` is not recognized. I am doing my code in C++. If anyone could help me I would be so grateful.

Documentation explain that the function to use is:

```
#include "<webots/Emitter.hpp>"

namespace webots {
  class Emitter : public Device {
    virtual int send(const void *data, int size);
    // ...
  }
}
```

But I don´t have idea how works this.

Answer (score 1):

You will find a simple example of using an `Emitter` in C++ [here](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/projects/languages/cpp/controllers/driver/driver.cpp). The corresponding `Receiver` code is [here](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/projects/languages/cpp/controllers/slave/slave.cpp). That should clarify the use of these methods.